# Determine whether a multi-character literal equals one value or another

Tags: c++, if-statement

This is a really simple thing, but I'm wondering if there's a way to check if a multi-character literal is equal to one of two (or more) multi-character literals.

The code I want to change would be something like this:

```
if (value == 'test' || value == 'example')
```

I thought perhaps it would be something along the lines of

```
if (value == ('test' | 'example')
```

...but this doesn't seem to work. Is there actually a way to do it? I'd imagine so.

Comment: What benefit do you see in your imagined approach? What do you want out of this?

Comment: @netcoder - the code is valid. `'test'` is a multi-character literal. Its type is `int` and its value is implementation defined. It's not the right thing to use here, of course. (Back in the olden days, programs for the Macintosh had IDs that were typically written as a multi-character literal with four characters; the value contained the four ASCII value for the characters).

Comment: @netcoder it was actually an oversight on my part, I'm using char - I assumed they worked in the same way.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I know of multichar literals. My point was that the default implementation of `std::string` doesn't provide an operator for it, and the C string comparison would fail (btw, I assumed `std::string` and C strings specifically because he said "string").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply enough, no, there isn't. What you would try to do there is a bitwise OR on the two strings, which I don't think is a defined operator for `std::string`.

You could though write a variadic function to do this for you, although it's probably more work than just doing it normally.

Comment: the OP's code does a bitwise OR between two *integers* specified as multibyte literals

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
std::string const s = "blah blah";
if( s == "test" || s == "example" )
{
    // ...
}
```

you can also check whether the string is a member of a `std::set`.

e.g.

```
static char const* const data[] = {"test", "example"};
set<string> const values( data, data + 2 );


if( values.find( "blah blah" ) != values.end() )
{
    cout << "found!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: @slugonamission: It uses string literals instead of multibyte char literals ;)

Comment: @slugonamission: you ask, "How is this different from the OP's code?". how is it not different?

Comment: Because your first code sample is identical to the OP's first code sample. I might be misunderstanding something here though.

Comment: @slugonamission double quotes `"` and single quotes `'`, and an explicit `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Any variable can only be compared to one value at a time and you can't 'OR' strings...so no, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
std::vector<string> v;
v.push_back("Test");
v.push_back("Example");

if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), stringToMatch) != v.end())
{
  //It was similar to one of the strings
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use this kind of approach, I'd generally prefer a different container. It's fine for two strings but it will scale badly.

Comment: What other container would you use @JackAidley?

Comment: @AdriánPérez an `unordered_set` for large sets of values.

Answer (score 1):

The closer you'll get are regular expressions, but they are only available in C++11 (or through an external library like PCRE) and they incur a lot of overhead compared to OR'ed comparisons so I doubt you wanna go that way for something that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of strings and check for existence. As others have noted an [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) can be more efficient for look-up.

```
unordered_set<string> validStrings = {"test",
                                      "example"};

if(validStrings.count("example") > 0) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

*edit*

Wrap this up in a class:

```
template<typename Type>
class Container {
    unordered_set<Type> values;
public:
    //...
    bool contains(const Type& value) const {
        return values.count(values) > 0;
    }
};
```

And use as:

```
Container<string> validStrings = {"test",
                                  "example"};

if(validStrings.contains("example") {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I'll now follow around, repeating everything you say.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

- Use a regular expression ([`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) or [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)):

  ```
  const boost::regex r("test|example");
  if (boost::regex_match(s, r))
  {
  }
  ```
- Populate a container with the strings and search the container:

  ```
  std::set<std::string> strings { "example", "test" };
  if (strings.count(s) > 0)
  {
  }
  ```
- or what you have in the question.

Comment: as i recall `std::regex` isn't implemented in MinGW g++ 4.7.2 (the latest I have), so it's still a bit unportable. but boost should be okay.

Comment: Cool your suggestion of using RegEx. However, I would suggest a Map instead of a Set.

Comment: @Markon, why a `map`? There is no associated value with the string.

Comment: Well you're right, but I guess that searching for a string among 100'000 other strings can be quite slow (at least O(logn)). Maybe a Map with an empty char as value will increase the memory usage, but could save running time ( get is O(1) ).

Comment: @Markon, a `set` is ordered also.

Comment: You're right, but I only suggested a different solution :) Of course, I would try to understand what I need: more insertions or searches?